# How do people measure how many calories or proteins/fats/сarbohydrates are in some food?

Tags: proteins, food, nutrition

How is the composition (in fats, proteins or carbohydrates) of a certain food estimated and how is the amount of calories provided by the food calculated?

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-food-manufacturers/

Comment: https://carolina.com/teacher-resources/Interactive/food-calorimetry+/tr23949.tr

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackExchange. Question is nice but would be better if you add some research you've done

Answer (score -1):

Messured by the amount of energy it will take to raise 1 degree celsius in 1 kg of water. You really can never go by what the packaging says either. All depending on how food is prepared, even your digestion differs the count person to person.